# "Set As Wallpaper" right-click option in Nautilus does not work

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 and when I right click a photo and select "Set As Wallpaper" the function does not work. But I am able to get it working by going into **System Settings** and using the <kbd>+</kbd> button in *Personalization* to set a new wallpaper. It's very annoying though, is there any way to fix this problem?

updates:

- I tested on another account and the problem went away
- there are no other DEs installed. GNOME was previously installed but it is now uninstalled.

update:

it doesn't work on Thunar either. Forgot to say that I had recently switched to Thunar for my file manager (but my desktop is still Unity)

Comment: Does this happen for all images, irrespective of image type or is it only for, say, png or jpg pr whatever?

Comment: Have you installed any other Desktop Environment such as Gnome-Shell or Cinnamon?

Comment: So what exactly happens? Does your desktop image change to anything? Or does it just stay as the previous one? Please also check whether or not the image you are trying to set as your wallpaper is present in the `~/Pictures/Wallpapers` folder ones you have tried to make it your wallpaper.

Comment: And I am assuming that this is in Nautilus?

Comment: Open your picture in Image Viewer, right click on your picture now and select Set as Wallpaper. Does this work?

Comment: @paranoid panda no it stays exactly the same and yes it is in the default Nautilus on unity

Comment: @anwar no I haven't

Comment: @terdon yes, for all images

Comment: @JamesTobin I've added an answer and let me know if that works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OP installed Gnome Shell on top over Ubuntu at some point in time. Though removed later, It left some user-specific settings on user's profile.

Open a terminal and use these two commands to fix the problem.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.background active true
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true
```

- The first command restore the right click -> Set as Wallpaper functionality
- Second one gives you the ability to right click on the desktop to bring the menu.

After that two command, use this to set nautilus handle your desktop

```
xdg-mime default nautilus-folder-handler.desktop inode/directory
```

That should fix the problem for nautilus.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this would not work using the "Dark" theme. The Nautilus right-click option would only change the background when I switched to the "Light" theme. Changing the wallpaper from the Settings menu worked with either theme.